# What kind of Ethernet cabling would I need for through the attic - And what cat?

Tags: walls, attic, ethernet, internet

I'm putting in an ethernet cable in my attic to reach from my modem in my library to my room, where I have my computer and an extra router (for better WiFi). Currently, I get internet in there from Powerline extenders.

I plan to run 2 cables, one for my PC and one for the router aforementioned.

My main question, is what type of cables and connectors should I use?
Is there any type of special cord I'd need since I'll be running cables through a wall and an attic? (If it matters, it won't be going through any exterior walls) And what type of plug should I use? (If there are types)

One more, what would be the best cat type to use? I was thinking about Cat 5e but my friends are telling me to run Cat 6 because it'll last longer and with improved speeds.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need one cable for the router. Your computer, printer and any other wired devices  can all connect to the router.

As far as cable type, I would install Cat 5e but you could future proof a bit more with Cat 6. Just a question of cable and jack costs - the work is the same.

I normally use plenum rated cable everywhere but I do commercial installs. That may not be necessary for your attic.

The most important thing is to wire jacks instead of putting connectors on the ends of a long cable. A little extra work but far more professional and reliable. You will need a jack (Cat 5e or 6 to match the cable) and either a wall plate and electrical box or box eliminator or a surface mount box on each end. Get a 110 punch tool and you're all set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; On the 2 cords, I need to cords so I can use my Steam link on the opposite side of the house. I don't plan on staying too long in this house So I'll just stick with Cat 5e then. On that last part, do you mean a wall outlet kinda thing but with ethernet instead of 120 V outlets? Because I was just thinking about running out the cords to the ceiling of my room from the attic (My PC is up against an exterior wall, and I don't want to deal with the insulation, plus there already is an opening from my room to my attic)

Comment: Correct. A "wall outlet kinda thing". But if you want a more temporary installation and don't need it to look permanent, then run the cords out from the ceiling and down the inside of the walls. But **terminate with jacks** in surface mount boxes and then use standard patch cables (the premade 7' or 14' type) from the surface mount box jacks to your computer. Even for relatively short term, that will provide MUCH better reliability than crimping plugs on the ends of the long cord.

Comment: You can run  one ethernet cable across the house and have a ethernet switch placed at the other end. With shorter ethernet cables, you can connect the switch to the various devices (Computer, printer, Steamlink, etc.) In that case, a Gigabit, or if you have the funds to go crazy, a ten-gigabit Ethernet switch will be satisfactory for your cause. General consumer rated Ethernet switches start with a handful of Ethernet ports, and can be easily upgraded without needing to run more wires across a home.